# resetting ubuntu password with grub2

Tags: boot, grub2

After I saw [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Reset_root_password) manual on resetting my password I decided to try it out and do the same steps on my machine. I edited `linux` line so that instead of having `ro  quite splash $vt_handoff` I have `rw init=/bin/bash`. But then I try to load it with `F10` I only get

```
  Booting a command list

Loading Linux 4.4.0-38-generic ...
Loading initial ramdisk ...
error: invalid video mode specification `text'
Booting in blind mode
```

After that boot process stops and I see nothing more. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @mikewhatever but isn't it for Linux in general? We only specify some linux kernel flags at this moment.

Comment: Perhaps it is, but then, a distro is much more then just a kernel, is it not.

Comment: @mikewhatever sure, but, for example, this guide is seems like for ubuntu  and it suggests the same steps https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-14-04-lost-password-recovery . Since we only specify kernel boot options, I think that it should be the same for all the distros, but Im not sure.

Comment: @mikewhatever but may be you are right. I tried it on Arch and it worked. But then there is another question (not to you, just in general) -- why so many sources (I provided only one of them, but I saw plenty) suggest this approach for ubuntu.